# In terminal, scrolling prints weird characters

Tags: terminal, high-sierra, ssh, macos

I was in an SSH session remotely using `vim`. For some reason, SSH crashed, and I was returned to my home shell. However, whenever I tried to scroll, instead of the terminal scrolling, it printed sets of characters. Also, it's hard to reproduce a single set of characters, because every few seconds, it prints different characters. They are always ASCII characters, like `` ` ``, `?`, `a`, `J`, etc.

Toggling the alternate screen does not help, and all my other terminal tabs work fine.

How can I fix this terminal session?

Comment: For now, I just closed the tab and opened a new one, which works fine, but it would be nice to know.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To fix this, just run the `reset` command. It will reinitialize the current terminal.

Comment: Run `man reset` to see the manual pages for reset.

Comment: Solid, but *why* does this occur?

Comment: I *think* it's a terminal client feature where other codepages can be chosen to draw graphics etc. Basically, a certain sequence of control codes can change your terminal client's mode, and to reset it you need to send some other control codes. `reset` helps with this.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17682934/linux-terminal-typing-feedback-gone-line-breaks-not-displayed/49790857